# Android how to drop the ongoing call

Tags: android, telephony

Can it possible to disconnect ongoing call using the app.I have get out the code http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html and  there are also may app in market that support this feature like https://market.android.com/details?id=ctsoft.androidapps.calltimer&feature=search_result

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Its Possible using Itelyphony Interface in andorid you can hang both incoming and outgoing call in android
Search for Iteklyphony interface in andorid 
I have done one application on that
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cell.MyCellFamily.UI&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jZWxsLk15Q2VsbEZhbWlseS5VSSJd

Comment: use silenceRinger() instead and endcall() method instead of setMute()